# Getting same sized bitmap from an imageView

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, android-glide, bitmapimage

I'm making an app that cuts a circle shape from a large image and saves it as a thumbnail.

To do this I have created a FrameLayout to enclose an ImageView and a CustomView whose dimensions match the parent.  Glide is used to load the image into the ImageView.  And the custom view which sits on top of the imageview has onclick methods that allow a user to drag a scalable circle around the image.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="357dp"
    android:layout_height="247dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <!--app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />-->

    <com.example.christopher.thumbnailtest.ThumbnailFrame
        android:id="@+id/ThumbnailFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Currently, I am trying to create a bitmap that is the exact same size as the ImageView.

```
public void cropImage(View view) {

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    Log.d("bitmap", bitmap.toString());

    //Create a bitmap with the same dimensions (thumbnail)
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Log.d("BITMAP_WIDTH", String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth()));
    Log.d("BITMAP_Height", String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));

    //Create new canvas with our bitmap to draw into
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    //Set a paint object for a solid colored object
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(0XFF000000);

    //Get a handle on current image object
    ThumbnailFrame thumbnail = findViewById(R.id.ThumbnailFrame);

    //Draw a small circle on the new bitmap (thumbnail) with the same dimensions as that of our thumbnail frame.
    canvas.drawCircle(thumbnail.getyPosit(), thumbnail.getxPosit(), thumbnail.getradius(), paint);
    Log.d("XPOSIT", String.valueOf(thumbnail.getxPosit()));
    Log.d("YPOSIT", String.valueOf(thumbnail.getyPosit()));
    Log.d("RADIUS", String.valueOf(thumbnail.getradius()));

    //Use Porter.Duff method to make picture ONLY exist in a new bitmap
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    //Crop new bitmap with createBitmap
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    //Compress?  and save new bitmap as a thumbnail, and send thumbnail URI 
}
```

Sadly, the image which comes back is not the same size as the frame and on certain images the bitmap size changes.  When a star shape was originally loaded is was 150 x 150, for this particular image it is (988 x 988) but the dimensions of the imageview should extend past that and are rectangular not square.

```
D/bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@491f236

D/BITMAP_WIDTH: 988

D/BITMAP_Height: 988

D/XPOSIT: 1378.0

D/YPOSIT: 938.0

D/RADIUS: 50.0
```

Is there a method to get an exact bitmap version of an imageView which is the exact same size?

Note:  It doesn't need to be scaled to the dimensions of the imageview, but the bitmap should be the exact same size perhaps filling the extra space with alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

After doing further research, I learned that you should **never** use
`image.buildDrawingCache();` or `Bitmap bmap = image.getDrawingCache();`

These are deprecated methods now and the result for me was a distorted image that was only partially loaded.

If you are trying to do what I did, convert the position of the circle in your picture to the measurements of the bitmap.  This can be easily done, especially if your imageview is particularly square

`[( x coord. of circle) / (imageview width)] * [bitmap width]`

using...

```
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

If you are trying to take a screen shot of your image view, there is PixelCopy(), I have no idea how to use it but it is documented on the website.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy